# Directly booting to Ubuntu 14.04 without a Windows boot option

Tags: 14.04, boot

I cannot see a way to boot to Windows after I installed Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit

My laptop is directly booting into Ubuntu.

Any help on how to be able to be able to boot to Windows would be appreciated.

Comment: So, no GRUB screen at all?  Sounds like you need to "repair GRUB".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try updating the grub with `sudo update-grub`? It will tell you if windows partition is detected. If it is detected just reboot.

Comment: i am new to ubuntu how to update the grub?

Comment: i did write than code and it showed windows 8 loader found what to do now?

Comment: If it is detected just reboot the computer.

Comment: thanks a lot that helped one more problem is i cant see the drive in which windows is installed on ubuntu and cant see the drive in which ubuntu is installed on windows pls suggest something

Comment: Yw @shubhi-dimri. Well, you can use `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda` to see what partitions you have on Ubuntu. The Windows partition, I suppose, will appear as **HPFS/NTFS/exFAT**.

Comment: oh yes its showing same way as you mentioned but i have created 3 partition and only 2 drives are shown both in windows and ubuntu cant i see the 3rd drive?

Comment: well, I can't understand what you mean, maybe the best way is start another ask and show the outputs to make us an idea. If you do it, copy here the link from your ask for me hehe :P

Comment: sorry i was mistaken everything is fine thanks a lot for your help :)